# finding blank cells with formula

Tags: excel, vba

In a list with many columns and cells we need to enter different data and to protect every cell with some data from doing some changes to them. All empty cells don't need any protection and should stay unprotected, but after writing for ex. some values and running this macro they should stay protected.

That macro works perfectly fine as long my cells are really blank without value or formula.
Now I need to use it in an new list where we have some formulas to write "N/A" if some events in columns occours.

**=IF([@[Data File needed?]]="No","N/A","")**
If in "Column Data File needed?" **"no"** will be chosen, then put in other column automatically "N/A", in case there is no **"no"** cell stays empty

How should I change that part of code to find to leave empty cells with my code too unprotected?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim isTrustedUser As Boolean
    Dim currentUsr As String

Call Settings

    currentUsr = Environ("username")
    isTrustedUser = currentUsr = Adminuser1 Or currentUsr = Adminuser2 _
    Or currentUsr = Adminuser3 Or currentUsr = Adminuser4 Or currentUsr = Adminuser5 Or currentUsr = Adminuser6 Or Adminuser7
         

     
With Checkliste
        
     .Unprotect Password:=strpassword
     .Cells.Locked = True

    On Error Resume Next
        .Range("B1:AS70").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    On Error GoTo 0
        .Protect Password:=strpassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
        
End With
     


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want to unlock a cell with a formula? The user shouldn't be able to change it - although it might show as empty.

Comment: The same here. In your code, the `xlCellTypeBlanks` although it says blank, refers to empty cells. Blank cells are a larger group and consist of the aforementioned empty cells, cells evaluating to `""` (`=""`) and cells containing a single quote (`'`), i.e. cells containing `=""` and `'` are not empty and are not considered via `xlCellTypeBlanks`. Using these terms (blank, empty), could you try to explain what is happening and what you would like to happen?

Comment: You can loop through `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` and check if `LEN(Cell)=0`

Comment: I know. It's uncommon to use formula unprotected. In that specific worksheet they are not that important. They should only save some time ans mistakes in filling of that sheet columns. If you chose one of two options in ex. column B you should fill column C-F with "N/A". So those formulas are there to save some time. But after being filled with "N/A" they should be protected.

Comment: So I can use `.Range("B1:AS70").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = False` that line together with `.Range("B1:AS70").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False` to get all cells with some values or text protected and leave all cells without values and formulas unprotected. It almost what I need, but perfect would be cells with formulas that are showing text like "N/A" instead of pseudo blank `""` stay too protected.